# Oracle sql - Selecting the difference between two sums from two different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, aggregate-functions

Say I have two tables, which I want to calculate their sum differences:

```
company1(
id INTEGER,
salary INTEGER
)

company2(
id INTEGER,
salary INTEGER
)
```

How can I select the difference between their SUM(salary) from each of their employees using only one select query?

For example:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(company1.salary) FROM company1 GROUP BY id) - (SELECT SUM(company2.salary) FROM company2 GROUP BY id) as diff_between_pay
```

The end results would be like:

```
company1
id   salary  
1    40000
2    20000
3    50000

company2
id   salary
1    30000
2    15000
3    25000

end result differences:
id
1    10000
2    5000
3    25000
```

Comment: What `sum` are you talking about in `sum(salary)`? `id` is primary key in each table (and presumably that is employee id), so there is only one salary for each employee in each table - so what **sum** are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a `select`:

```
select (select sum(salary) from company1) - (select sum(salary) from company2) as diff_between_pay
from dual;
```

For your revised question, use a `full join`:

```
select ( coalesce(c1.sums, 0) - coalesce(c2.sums, 0) ) as diff_between_pay
from (select id, sum(salary) as sums
      from company1
      group by id
     ) c1 full join
     (select id, sum(salary) as sums
      from company2
      group by id
     ) c2
     on c1.id = c2.id;
```

Comment: Apologizes, I was still editing my question. I left out an important piece. What if the sums from each company was GROUPED BY id? Meaning that you have multiple rows from each sum, instead of a single row.

Comment: The revised question worked out and gave me the exact result I wanted. Although I think you forgot a ", 0" in the second coalesce argument. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. If ID is primary key, what is the meaning of GROUPING by ID?

Comment: @mathguy Oh, your right. I apologize, it was not meant to be ID, the example I came up with should have had more thought put into it. It was meant to be a non-primary key instead of ID.